# Help needed in the proof related to the support function for two convex sets

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have read following problem from the convex optimization book (by Stephen Boyd).[image]

Although the solution is available but I want to prove it from another line of reasoning. We have to prove that if support functions of two convex closed sets are equal then the sets are equal. Suppose if for certain vector $y$, $x^*\in C$ and $z^* \in D$ are the maximizers in $C$ and $D$ respectively. Then we have to show that $x^*=z^*$ for every possible $y$. Since the support function is assumed to be equal for any $y$ therefore we can say that $x^*$ is not element wise greater than $z^*$ (and similarly $z^*$ is not element wise greater than $x^*$) since other wise we may have $y^T(x^*-z^*)\neq 0$ for $y$'s  that have only positive elements. But I do not know how to show the other possibilities of $x^*\neq z^*$ are also not possible. I will be very thankful to you your help in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your reasoning is quite wrong since $x^*$ and $z^*$ are *dependent* on $y$, so you can't (once you have them) choose a different value of $y$ and choose $y$ that has only positive elements.

Comment: @5xum yes you are right. But I wanted to say that if we have chosen a $y$ (whose elements are all positive) and then we look for the maximizers in $C$ and suppose the maxmizer in $C$ is $x^*$ then we should not look for members of $D$ which are element wise smaller than $x^*$ because they cannot have same support as that achieved by $x^*$. I think my writing was confusing. Is it clear now? Or is it still wrong reasoning?

Comment: @5xum anyway if my reasoning is wrong then please guide me how I can make it correct. Thank you.

Comment: don't use images for asking questions